# Time format in SAS HHMMSS

Tags: sas

The following program in SAS EG 9.3 is giving me results as below:

```
DATA work.header;
calculation='"A00",'
||'"399",' 
|| '"NOM",' 
|| PUT(DATE(), yymmddn8.)
||","
||put(time(),hhmm8.2);
Run;
```

Results I'm getting as below:

"A00","399","NOM",20141028,10:03.76

However I would like the time to be "100345" like hhmmss?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The format to use is `TIME8.`, which will give you a time of the format HH:MM:SS

e.g.

```
put(time(),time8.);
```

Gives:

```
10:46:40
```

To remove the colons from this, you'll have to use string functions, I would go for:

```
compress(put(time(),time8.),'','dk');
```

Which only keeps the numeric characters, giving:

```
104640
```

Comment: I would like time to be without colons in it, i.e. 104640.

Comment: Many Thanks for answer it was spot on.